# Purpose of travel for past trips on a d-2-8 visa

Tags: visas, south-korea

I'm applying for a D-2-8 visa (Summer school/short term study visa) to go South Korea.

One of the questions is what the purpose of visit was for my past travel history. I've been to England, France, Germany and The Netherlands on a school trip. I also frequently go on holidays to Germany.

So the question is: can I put 'school trip' as the 'purpose of visit' or should I put 'tourism'?

Also since I went to Germany more than once during the last 5 years, should I put more than one date or the most recent date? And should I put 'school trip + tourism' under 'purpose of visit' for this country?

Another question is: I put 'D-2-8 SHORT TERM STUDY VISA' in the '2.2 Status of Stay' section. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking what to put on the purpose of trip for the travel history items: EG your school trips to Germany, or what to put for the purpose for your overall visa (which would be for Korean summer school under 90 days). Or for both?

Comment: @Uciebila what should I put as a purpose of visit with the countries I've visited in the last 5 years?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, have just edited the post a little to make that clearer :)